# Understand pipe and redirection command

Tags: bash, pipe

I want to understand the real power of pipe and redirection command.As per my understanding,`|` takes the output of one command result as the input of itself. And, `>` is helps in output redirecting .If it is so,

```
find . -name "*.swp" | rm 
find . -name "*.swp" > rm
```

why this command is not working as expected .For me above command means

1. Find the all files recursively whose extension is .swp in current directory .
2. take the output of `1.`  and remove all whose resulted  files .

FYI,yes i know how to accomplish this task . it can be done by passing `-exec` flag .

```
find . -name "*.swp"-exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But as I already mentioned,i want to accomplish it with `>` or `|` command.
 
If i was wrong and going in wrong direction,please correct me and explain redirection and pipe command. Where we use whose commands ? please dont mention simple book examples i read all whose thing . try to explain me some complicated thing .

Comment: `>` is output redirection. `<` is input redirection.

Comment: You are getting stuck on the distinction between standard input and the command line. You want the `$(  )` operator in bash, or the `-exec` option of find, or (perhaps your best choice) `xargs`. No energy to write a real answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll break this down by the three methods you have shown:

- `>` will redirect all output from `find` into a file named `rm` (will not work, because you're just appending to a file).
- `|` will pipe output from `find` into the `rm` command (will not work, because `rm` does not read on `stdin`)
- `-exec rm -rf {} \;` will run `rm -rf` on each item (`{}`) that `find` finds (will work, because it passes the files as argument to `rm`).

You will want to use `-exec` flag, or pipe into the `xargs` command (`man xargs`), not `|` or `>` in order to achieve the desired behavior.

**EDIT:** as @dmckee said, you can also use the `$()` operator for string interpolation, ie: `rm -rf $(find . -name "*.swp")` (this will fail if you have a large number of files, due to argument length limits).

Comment: You can use also shell globbing (`rm -rf **/*.swp`) to achieve your stated (example) goal, but a bit outside the scope of the question (shell piping and redirection).

Comment: string interpolation is changing stdout into stdin , is it like that .

Comment: @Dear: No, it's not. You shell will see the `$()`, and substitute it with the output of the command in the `$()`, before starting the program. An example makes this clearer.

If I have `echo "foo$(echo 'bar')"`, the shell will substitute the `$()`, and will really execute `echo "foobar"`.

Answer (score 3):

> simply redirects to a file named rm.
Piping via | to rm doesn't work because rm doesn't expect filenames via [STDIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).
So you have to use xargs, which passes values from STDIN as arguments:

```
find . -name "*.swp"|xargs rm
```

This is dangerous because the filename may contain characters your shell considers a field seperator ($IFS).
So, you use:

```
find . -name "*.swp" -print0|xargs -0 rm
```

Which causes find print the filenames \0 sperated to STDOUT and xargs to read the filenames \0 seperated and pass them as arguments to rm.

Of course, the easiest way to achieve this would have been:

```
rm **/*.swp
```

assuming you use bash.

Answer (score 1):

You should take some time and read about the basics of shell redirection again :) I think this is a good document: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial

I'll try to explain what went wrong for you:

```
find . -name "*.swp" | rm
```

This command redirects the find results, i.e. the `stdout` of find, to the `stdin` of the program `rm`. However, `rm` does not read on stdin (this is something you can read in the documentation of `rm`). `rm` is controlled via command line arguments, not via `stdin`. I think there is no way to make `rm` read from stdin at all. That's why nothing is deleted.

```
find . -name "*.swp" > rm
```

This command redirects newline-delimited find results (stdout of find) to a file called 'rm'. Again, nothing is deleted :)

Basically the `<`, `>`, `>>`, `&>`, `&>>` operators perform redirection from/to a **file** that actually exists in the file system. The pipe `|` redirects the standard output from one command to the standard input of another command. Simply spoken there are no files involved here. However, this approach only makes sense if the program to the left of the pipe actually writes something to `stdout` and the program to the right of the pipe reads from `stdin` **and** both programs understand each other, i.e. the reading program (the consumer) understands the output of the feeding program.

Answer (score 0):

Redirection creates a file. So your `>rm` example just creates a file named `./rm` into which the output of your command is saved.

Pipes are essentially a shorthand. `one | two` is like `one >tmp; two <tmp` except without the (explicit) temporary file.

Of course, `rm` doesn't read file names from standard input, so `cmd | rm` is basically useless (apart from situations where the pipeline continues with yet another command which does something with the input which `rm` didn't read). If you want that, there's `xargs`.

```
find . -name "*.swp" | xargs rm
```