# Shell script to compress a list of files

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, 7zip

I am actually using cygwin64. I would like to compress just a few selected files in a directory. Say, the 3 oldest files in the directory `myDir`. To get the 3 oldest files, this is what I do:

```
$ ls myDir -t | tail -3
file1
file2
file3
```

Now, the question is, how do I pass those 3 file(names) to, say `tar` or `7z`?

Here's what I've tried:

```
7z a myFile.7z (ls myDir -t | tail -3)
```

but that doesn't work -- bash complains about the `(`. Removing it doesn't help, and neither does adding `--` after `myFile.7z`. Same goes for `tar` instead of `7z`.

Comment: You dropped a `$`.  `7z a myFile.7z $(ls myDir -t | tail -3)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understand pipe and redirection command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394426/understand-pipe-and-redirection-command)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to gzip all files in all sub-directories in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363921/how-to-gzip-all-files-in-all-sub-directories-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use xargs with 7z or tar after the ls/tail command. I don't have a linux terminal now to test but below should work ->

```
ls myDir -t | tail -3 | xargs 7z a myFile.7z
```

Update -> To resolve path issue, here is the final solution.

```
ls -t -d -1 $PWD/myDir/* | tail -3 | xargs 7z a myFile.7z
```

Comment: I like your style. Would be nice to add something like "${files[@]/#/$dir/}", similar to what @kosolebox added in his answer (since `ls` doesn't include the dir path). Would that be possible in your approach?

Comment: I got your point. In that case use 'find' command instead of 'ls' command and your problem should be solved. I am not sure if you can still filter the files the way you can do it using ls. E.g. -> "find myDir "*" | xargs 7z a myFile.7z". Or else simply cd to myDir and run "ls -t | tail -3 | xargs 7z a myFile.7z"

Comment: Try this -> "ls -t -d -1 $PWD/myDir/* | tail -3 | xargs 7z a myFile.7z"

Answer (score 1):

Try this form instead:

```
dir='myDir'
readarray -t files < <(exec ls "$dir" -t1 | tail -3)
7z a myFile.7z "${files[@]/#/$dir/}"
```

- `-1` makes filenames get enumerated line by line
- `readarray` reads array of lines
- `"${files[@]/#/$dir/}"` inserts dir path on every filename

Try this script too:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1
DIR=$2

if [[ $FILE != *.7z ]]; then
    echo "Invalid filename for 7z archive: $FILE"
    echo "Usage: $0 filename.7z dir"
    exit 1
elif [[ ! -d $DIR ]]; then
    echo "Not a directory: $DIR"
    echo "Usage: $0 filename.7z dir"
    exit 1
fi

[[ $FILE != /* ]] && FILE=$PWD/$1

cd "$DIR" || {
    echo "Unable to change directory to $DIR."
    exit 1
}

readarray -t TARGETS < <(exec ls -t1)

7za a "$FILE" "${TARGETS[@]:(-3)}"
```

Save it in a file like `script.sh` and run it with `bash script.sh myFile.7z myDir`.

Another way:

```
( cd myDir; 7za a ../myFile.7z $(ls -t1 | tail -3); )
```

Or

```
( cd myDir; ls -t1 | tail -3 | xargs -d '\n' -- 7za a ../myFile.7z; )
```

Comment: I seem to be getting a "syntax error close to 'token' unexpected '<'"

Comment: @djas What do you get with `bash --version`?

Comment: "GNU bash, version 4.1.11(2)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)"

Comment: @djas. Runas `bash` first. Then run those commands. Also, try to execute those commands 1 by 1 just to avoid carriage returns.

Comment: I am clean of carriage returns, but `man readarray` returns "No manual entry for readarray". Do I need any package installed? (Sorry, what do you mean by "Runas `bash` first"?)

Comment: `readarray` is a bash builtin. Try `help readarray`. You may be executing your shell in `/bin/sh` not `bash`, so run `bash` first. I meant "Run" not "Run as" sorry..

Comment: @djas Try my script too.

Comment: it returns your message "Not a directory: myDir", where `myDir` is indeed a directory.

Comment: @djas Yes. One line should be `elif [[ ! -d $DIR ]]; then` not `elif [[ -d $DIR ]]; then`.

Comment: yep, worked now; running it instead as `sh script.sh myFile.7z myDir` doesn't work. could you please explain?

Comment: @djas What was working already? The script or the new suggestions?

Comment: the script worked; the new suggestions also (they were in fact the comment and answer of Brain Cain and dganesh2002). thanks! thinking of future users, I'll end up accepting dganesh2002's answer -- but I learned a lot from you today. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `7z`, but I think you are just missing the `$` before `()`:

```
7z a myFile.7z $(ls myDir -t | tail -3)
```

You can check your command by typing:

```
echo $(ls -t *.txt | head -3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over `ls` output [can be unreliable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Here's one way you can accomplish what you want using `stat`.

```
declare -A files
for file in myDir/*; do
    modified=$(stat -c "%Y" "$file")
    files["$modified"]="$file"
done
top_3_indices=$(for i in ${!files[@]}; do echo $i; done | sort -rn | head -n 3)
for i in ${top_3_indices[@]}; do
    7z a myFile.7z "${files[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: This will still have the `EOL` issue from parsing `ls`, `find` would be preferable.

Comment: @BroSlow Very true.  Please see updated solution that works reliably for file names with whitespace.